# Why is it sometimes fast and sometimes slow to use TDengine's Java API to concurrently store data

Tags: database

When I use TDengine's Java API to develop concurrent repositories, sometimes it's very fast, sometimes it's very slow. I want to know if anyone has noticed this phenomenon when developing similar functions, and what is probably causing it? Please explain, thank you!

Batch writing and concurrent writing are used, with approximately 100 entries written at a time and multiple tables written at once,

But I found that when it's fast, I'll finish writing 100 articles in 1 second, but when it's slow, it takes 10 seconds. This is too strange[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzM2o.jpg)